# Invalid Syntax when using print() function

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

Edit: I figured out how to add the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4atf0.png)

I'm learning Python (literally learning, in a class), and downloaded a Python shell to practice on my PC. One of the examples is using the "open" and "with" commands. When I tried to run it in my program, it says there is a invalid syntax error on the "print" command. I went into the built in Help programs to try to figure out what was wrong and I couldn't find it after over an hour. I tried using the examples in the tutorial of the program (using copy and paste), and it came out with the same thing.

Here's the code from the Help program:

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L
print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (highlights the first p in "print(f(1))"


>>> def f(a, L=[]):
...     L.append(a)
...     return L
... 
... print(f(1))
... print(f(2))
... print(f(3))
```

It comes up with a Invalid Syntax before the "p" in the "print(f(1))" line.

I've looked on here for close to an hour for an answer and can't find the answer. There were plenty of them AFTER "print" focused on the t, apparently there was a lot of confusion with the "print" command when Python went from 2 to 3, but nothing BEFORE the "print".

(If I could figure out how to do a screenshot on my PC, I'd show it in detail, but every time I try it messes up)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Are you sure that this code on its own reproduces the error?

Comment: All it says is "SyntaxError : Invalid Syntax".

Comment: You need an empty line between the end of the function and the `print`, otherwise the interpreter expects the `print` to be indented as a line of code in the function

Comment: I've tried running it a dozen times and it keeps coming up with the same thing. I've tried adding a colon : after the "return L" line, that gave a syntax error on the colon. I can't seem to make it work no matter how I try

Comment: I added the empty line (it was included in the original code, but I took it out) and the same error in the same place came up

Comment: To repeat my question with more detail: if you put this code in a file all by itself and run it in Python, does it produce the same error?  If so, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Samwise Its 3.10.4. Part of the problem is I was in a video "lecture" on how to open and print the file, that's what led me to the Help file and then to the Help file code I listed. I also added a screenshot to show the error I get

Comment: Is that line really empty, or does it have space characters?

Comment: @KellyBundy it is empty. Zero space characters on the empty line, also zero space characters after the "L"

Comment: You can see quite clearly from your screenshot that the interpreter thinks you are still trying to define the function (the `...` at the beginning of the line). If you weren't, the line with `print(f(1))` would be preceded by `>>>`. So there must be something on that "empty" line...

Comment: Please select the seven lines with your mouse, then right-click the selection and choose "copy with prompt", then paste that into the question.

Comment: @KellyBundy >>> def f(a, L=[]):
...     L.append(a)
...     return L
... 
... print(f(1))
... print(f(2))
... print(f(3))

Comment: @Nick So it should have the >>> instead of the ... ?

Comment: Into the *question*. (Since comments mess it up.)

Comment: Sorry, should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zSsu.png

Comment: @Nick I got to the first "print" line and it came back with  "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    print (f(1))
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 2, in f
    L.append(a)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append' "

Comment: @KellyBundy got it. Sorry, I'm trying to figure this site out as well lol

Comment: @Nick so it should have the [1] etc after the print line as well?

Comment: @JeffLeobold yeah, that's the output of the function

Comment: @Nick in the file in your comment it has the [1] after the print line. That's the answer, and that's where it should show up?

Comment: @JeffLeobold yes

Comment: @Nick Ok, I think I figured it out. And if so, I did it to myself. I had the "with" and "open" part of the test still in the Python program. I restarted it and it worked like a charm. I think I just screwed up by not closing out my old work

Comment: @KellyBundy I think I figured out my mistake. Thank you so much for your help. If I could upvote comments, I would do so (don't know if its even possible).

Comment: Good to hear! I'm not sure this comment thread has much value to others though, so you should probably just delete the question

Comment: @JeffLeobold no worries at all - we've all been beginners :)

Comment: @Nick it can be used as a bad example :D

Comment: If you want, in that case you should probably answer it yourself and try to explain carefully what you did that caused the problem.

Comment: @Nick that is a good idea. Help out the new ones from basic mistakes

Comment: "with" and "open"? I don't see any of that in your screenshot.

Comment: @KellyBundy it was way up in the code. It was part of what I was originally working on. When I finally got around to screenshotting, it was more than 100 lines up.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not convinced. Your screenshot shows a NameError, meaning that did get executed. And later you even have a shell restart (although I'm used to seeing the Python version printed as first line, but I can't test that right now).

Comment: @KellyBundy I did the shell restart to try a reset like I'd been shown before. I thought it was the equivalent of "Did you turn it off and on again?" When I closed and reopened the Python program (the actual "turn it off and on again") it worked like a charm. I can send you the original code I used to see if you could replicate it if you'd like (built one .txt file and 5 lines of code).

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did was to open a file, when I came across an error. In looking for help, I tried to use code I found in the Help documentation. That didn't work either.

I didn't close the file I originally opened, and that caused the errors in the later code.

Here's a tip to the beginners, make sure your file is closed before you start a new series of code, even close and reopen the Python editor to make sure.

Thank you to Nick, Kelly Bundy, and Samwise for all the help and patience. If I could figure out how to upvote you, I would.

Answer (score -1):

I think this works properly, maybe the problem is in the interpreter or python installation itself
[image: Google colab]